# NServiceBus distrubutor sample

Tags: nservicebus

I started to learn about NServiceBus, and anyone knows if there any sample for distrubutor?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://mikaelkoskinen.net/post/nservicebus-distributor-sample-application.aspx

Comment: Thanks for your link.  Do you also know if there are any samples for pub/sub with distubutor?

Comment: Just configure your workers to share the same subscription storage. This will make pub/sub work as expected!  HTH